# Right click works as a hover in pure css without js

Tags: css, hover

I have a header with popup menu which appears from the left when I hover onto the certain part of the header. But when I make right click somewhere on the screen the popup menu appears, like the right click works as a hover. There is no js at all only css. I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: could you pls show code?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow :) Please visit [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how to properly ask a question. In order to better assist you, could you provide us with the code you're working with ?

Comment: Could you show us some code to help you? :)

Comment: you should reproduce the issue on a short, self contained example as a snippet in the question itself.